# Rails Call Custom Controller Action from Custom Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In a Rails project, I have the following controller action for the controller exchanges.rb:

```
def update_ordid

# Get the active exchange
@exchange = Exchange.find(params[:id])

# Decide which order ID field to update
active_order_field = params[:ordfld]    

# Save the order ID
order_id = params[:ordid]

if active_order_field == 1 then
  @exchange.order_id_1 = order_id
else
  @exchange.order_id_2 = order_id
end

@active_exchange.save
respond_with(@exchange)

end
```

I've set up a route to this controller action:

```
resources :exchanges do
    collection do
      get 'update_ordid'
    end
end
```

I want to call this action that accepts an order ID from a form on an exchanges show.html.erb page. I need to pass three values:

1. The ID of the current exchange, such as the integer in this example URL localhost:3000/exchanges/2 (This is the page the form is on)
2. The order ID as input from a text-field
3. Which of the two possible exchange fields the action should update

Next I need to create a custom form which will pass these values as parameters to the action. I haven't been able to find a good tutorial on how to do this yet, but my first thought was to set up the following:

```
<%= form_for(@exchange) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :ordid, "Order ID" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :ordid, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<% if @isrequestor == true %>
  <%f.hidden_field :ordfld, :value => "1" %>
<% else %>
  <%f.hidden_field :ordfld, :value => "2" %>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

This gives me a NoMethodError stating the method 'ordid' is undefined. I'm guessing I need to modify the first line of code to associate the form with the custom action I've set up, but have no idea how to do so properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yah, I got your point. So you wanted the following thing:

- You wrote an custom action
- You wanted to submit a form that action
- You have registered your action in the router.

So let me answer the following solutions and find some mistakes you made in your code.

```
# in route.rb
resources :exchanges do
  patch :update_ordid, on: :member # this is the best practice I would say, 
         #when you are trying to modify an existing record. So this action will only
         #be reached with patch http methods
         # on :member action an parameter id is required.
end
```

now if you generate your routes by running:

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

you will see a path like:

```
update_ordid_exchange  /exchange/:id/update_ordid # :id parameter for exchange record
```

in your form set the url:

```
<%= form_for(@exchange, url: update_ordid_exchange_path) do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= form_for(@exchange, url: url_for(controller: :exchange, action: update_ordid)) do |f| %>
```

Now then you will this form can submit this values within the parameter in your desire field.

So let me summarize things up here:
1. Setup your route properly
2. Check the url based on your route by generating rake routes command as shown above
3. Set the proper url and check if http method is correctly define in your form helper. For member actions, form helper by default use patch as http method. you just have to set the url.

Hope you understand my flow.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've implemented this code but am still getting the NoMethodError on the line '<%= f.text_field :ordid, class: "form-control" %>' I'm guessing this is because :ordid is not an actual field in the exchange table, but is a custom parameter I'd like to pass as if I was calling the action from a url like 'link_to "Update Order ID", update_ordid_exchange(ordfld: 1, ordid: value from form), :method => :post'

Comment: you can certainly do that. just use 
text_field_tag :ordid
so you will get it as a parameter param[:ordid] or if you wish you can directly pass through your url in the form. :)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried <%= f.text_field_tag :ordid, class: "form-control" %> but am getting "undefined method text_field_tag".

Comment: so is that answer is helping?

Comment: It looks like it got me farther, but I'm still getting an error when trying to render the form. This time it states undefined method `text_field_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x477e0d0>

Comment: Ended up fixing it by removing f. from the line in question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!